# Song at end of Warehouse 13 season 4

Tags: music-identification, warehouse-13

I'm binge-watching *Warehouse 13* and my Google-fu cannot identify this song that helps to end season 4.

The tune was a powerful feminine drumbeat when Claudia dismisses her best friends and marches back into the Warehouse to meet her oppressor.

The chorus seems to to run with:

> You are the resolation
>   You wanna get by
>   You are the revelation
>   ...

I've tried Googling and YouTube searches on the lyrics I remember.

YouTube turns up nothing for those lyrics but modern rap. Google shows some pages for *'warehouse 13 song list'* but none list the song I'm looking for and at least a few stretch my anti-malware. The credits show no attribution for the musical effort.

This is most likely some indie music from the 2011-2013 era. IIRC, there was a lot of indie music involved with this production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ["No Light, No Light"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Light,_No_Light) by Florence and the Machine.

> You want a revelation
>   Some kind of resolution
>   You want a revelation

Comment: I didn't come to grips with the subtext of the lyrics but now that I have seen.heard it in its entirety, I'm viewing that last 5 minutes of the episode in a different light.

Comment: That's a great band. Nice song I hadn't ever heard, too.